# How do I reattach this doorknob?

Tags: doors

The chassis has slots that you would expect the knob to fit into:

[image: chassis]

But the knob doesn't have them:

[image: knob]

If I push it in hard, it seems to stay on but isn't tight to the door.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that the inner ring screws in. I just have to turn it.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I saw a thread on the outside of the inner doorknob ring and inside of the latch hole.

Comment: Break out the rubber gloves!